# Unable to some videos in chrome cast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am using CastCompanionLibrary-android for chromecast integration.

I am going to show few methods of chromecast integration

first one is configuration initalization in application cast

```
private void initchromecast() {
    String applicationId = getString(R.string.app_id);

    // Build a CastConfiguration object and initialize VideoCastManager
    CastConfiguration options = new CastConfiguration.Builder(applicationId)
            .enableAutoReconnect()
            .enableCaptionManagement()
            .enableDebug()
            .enableLockScreen()
            .enableNotification()
            .enableWifiReconnection()
            .setCastControllerImmersive(true)
            .setLaunchOptions(false, Locale.getDefault())
            .setNextPrevVisibilityPolicy(CastConfiguration.NEXT_PREV_VISIBILITY_POLICY_DISABLED)
            .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_REWIND, false)
            .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE, true)
            .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_DISCONNECT, true)
            .setForwardStep(10)
            .build();
    VideoCastManager.initialize(this, options);
}
```

and TO pass meta data

```
private void loadRemoteMedia(int position, boolean autoPlay) {
                MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);

                mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, TITLE);

                MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(
                         path)
                        .setContentType("application/x-mpegURL")
                        .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
                        .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                        .setStreamDuration(MediaInfo.UNKNOWN_DURATION)
                        .build();

                                mCastManager.startVideoCastControllerActivity(getActivity(), mediaInfo, position, autoPlay);

            }
```

Now my question is in below cod when i pass CastCompanion sample id **4F8B3483**  ,i can successfully cast most of the videos but when i put my sample application reciver id some of the videos which works with their id does not work with mine.

For example http://iptvcanales.com/xw/peliculas.php?movie=006 url works with CastCompanion reciver id but not with mine id in my code.